# Irregular shaped buttons using OBShapedButton with hidden image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, transparency

I am trying to make an irregular shaped button with the OBShapedButton class. That's ok, created it without any problem, however I need the image to be transparent. So, I just want an area from the image which will be clickable, but the image won't be seen.
I tried setting alphas on image, imageView and on the button itself, however it doesn't work neither way.

How should I do it?

Maybe it could be done by something else, not an UIButton, but unfortunately I didn't find anything on the net that I could understand and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the easiest way on how to do this is:

1. Subclass UIButton and add touchesBegan, touchesEnded, touchesMoved,
   touchesCancelled.
2. Then on touchesBegan, hide the image of the button and show the correct image in background.
3. And finally on touchesEnded or touchesMoved, show again the image of the button.

Hope it will help someone :)